# Problem while copying an Opencv Image into a bigger one

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to copy an OpenCV image into a bigger image, but I'm getting some problems. I want to create a bigger image that has a border of an specific size but I do not want to change that border. So, I'd like to change just the center part of the image with the same size of it. 
Here is the code I'm using.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "useful_tools.h"

int main()
{
    Useful_Tools ut;

    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("/home/felippe/Codigos_Cpp/Image_Registration_2D/square_landscape.jpeg");
    cv::Mat gray_image(image.rows, image.cols, image.type());
    cv::cvtColor(image, gray_image, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::Mat sobel_x(3, 3, CV_64F);

    //Filling the Sobel Filter
    sobel_x.at<double>(0, 0) = -1;
    sobel_x.at<double>(0, 1) = -2;
    sobel_x.at<double>(0, 2) = -1;
    sobel_x.at<double>(1, 0) =  0;
    sobel_x.at<double>(1, 1) =  0;
    sobel_x.at<double>(1, 2) =  0;
    sobel_x.at<double>(2, 0) =  1;
    sobel_x.at<double>(2, 1) =  2;
    sobel_x.at<double>(2, 2) =  1;

    cv::Mat edge = ut.correlation(gray_image, sobel_x, "zeros");

    return 0;
}
```

function

```
cv::Mat PadImage(cv::Mat image, int k_cols, int k_rows)
{
    //There is an error when k_rows or k_rows are even numbers.
    //cv::Mat image_padded(image.rows + k_rows - 1, image.cols + k_cols - 1, image.type());

    //Fixing:
    cv::Mat image_padded(image.rows + (k_rows/2)*2, image.cols + (k_cols/2)*2, image.type());
    image_padded = 0;

    //if (!padding_type.compare("zeros"))
    //{

    //Naming conventions are: x applies cols, and y applies rows
    //int x_add = k_rows / 2, y_add = k_cols / 2;

    int y_add = k_rows / 2, x_add = k_cols / 2;

    for (int i = y_add; i < image.rows + y_add; i++)
        for (int j = x_add; j < image.cols + x_add; j++)
            image_padded.at<double>(i, j) = image.at<double>(i - y_add, j - x_add);
    //}

    return image_padded;
}

cv::Mat Useful_Tools::correlation(cv::Mat image, cv::Mat kernel, std::string padding_type)
{
    cv::Mat image_padded(image.rows + kernel.rows-1, image.cols + kernel.cols-1, image.type());
    image_padded = 0;
    cv::Mat result(image.rows, image.cols, image.type());
    result = 0;

    cv::Mat image_padded2 = PadImage(image, 3, 3);

    showImage(image, "Original Image");
    showImage(image_padded2, "Image Padded");

    if (!padding_type.compare("zeros"))
    {
        int x_add = kernel.rows/2, y_add = kernel.cols/2;
        for (int i = x_add; i < image.rows + x_add; i++)
            for (int j = y_add; j < image.cols + y_add; j++)
                image_padded.at<double>(i, j) = image.at<double>(i-x_add, j-y_add);
    }
    /*else if (!padding_type.compare("repeat"))
    {
        cv::Mat result(image.rows + kernel.rows/2, image.cols + kernel.cols/2, image.type());

        for (int i = (kernel.rows-1)/2; i < image.rows + (kernel.rows-1)/2; i++)
            for (int j = (kernel.cols-1)/2; j < image.cols + (kernel.cols-1)/2; j++)
                result.at<double>(i, j) = image.at<double>(i-(kernel.rows-1)/2, j-((kernel.cols-1)/2));
    }*/
    else if (!padding_type.compare("without"))
    {
        image_padded.release();
        cv::Mat image_padded = image;
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "Please enter with a valid padding value." << std::endl;

    //showImage(image_padded, "Testing Padding");
    cv::imwrite( "Padding_image.jpg", image_padded);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < result.cols; j++)
            for (int m = 0; m < kernel.rows; m++)
                for (int n = 0; n < kernel.cols; n++)
                {
                    std::cout << image_padded.at<double>(i+m+kernel.rows/2, j+n+kernel.cols/2) << std::endl
                              << kernel.at<double>(m, n) << std::endl;
                    result.at<double>(i, j) += image_padded.at<double>(i+m+kernel.rows/2, j+n+kernel.cols/2)*kernel.at<double>(m, n);
                    std::cout << std::endl;
                }

    return result;
}
```

Here is the input image that I'm using.
[image]
Here is an example of image that I'm getting as a result.
[image: Padded_Image]

I have done some other examples using vector and the result seems correct, so what is wrong with that code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I is iterating on x but you’re using image.rows, and j is iterating on y but you’re using image.cols - that doesn’t seem right.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Are you aware of [`cv::copyMakeBorder`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga2ac1049c2c3dd25c2b41bffe17658a36)? There is also a [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/da3/tutorial_copyMakeBorder.html) on how to use it.

Comment: using cv::Rect and subimages and .copyTo (or .resize) are nice functions to insert an image into another one.

Comment: I know those functions, but I'd like to try doing that by iterating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue I could find is in case `kernel.rows` or `kernel.cols` are **even**.

The size of your output image is `(image.rows + kernel.rows-1, image.cols + kernel.cols-1)`.
Size is going to be too small when `kernel.rows` or `kernel.cols` are even.

For example: in case `kernel.rows = 0`, the size of the output is going to be smaller than the input.

Suggested correction:

```
cv::Mat image_padded(image.rows + (kernel.rows/2)*2, image.cols + (kernel.cols/2)*2, image.type());
```

Dividing the (integer) value by 2 and then multiply be 2 covers both even and odd cases.

---

- Note about naming conversions:
  The naming convention is: `x` applies `cols`, and `y` applies `rows`.
  You have replaced the names, and made code reading difficult.

---

I am not sure if your issue is related to the problem I found.
It could also be a problem in the input or output (problem in the code parts you are not showing).

Here is a test sample code (I put some of your code in comments):

```
cv::Mat PadImage(cv::Mat image, int k_cols, int k_rows)
{
    //There is an error when k_rows or k_rows are even numbers.
    //cv::Mat image_padded(image.rows + k_rows - 1, image.cols + k_cols - 1, image.type());

    //Fixing:
    cv::Mat image_padded(image.rows + (k_rows/2)*2, image.cols + (k_cols/2)*2, image.type());
    image_padded = 0;

    //if (!padding_type.compare("zeros"))
    //{

    //Naming conventions are: x applies cols, and y applies rows
    //int x_add = k_rows / 2, y_add = k_cols / 2;

    int y_add = k_rows / 2, x_add = k_cols / 2;

    for (int i = y_add; i < image.rows + y_add; i++)
        for (int j = x_add; j < image.cols + x_add; j++)
            image_padded.at<double>(i, j) = image.at<double>(i - y_add, j - x_add);
    //}

    return image_padded;
}


int main()
{
    //Read input image as Grayscale (one byte per pixel).
    cv::Mat Iu8 = cv::imread("img.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    //Draw a white rectangle around the input image (for testing)
    cv::rectangle(Iu8, cv::Rect(0, 0, Iu8.cols - 1, Iu8.rows - 1), cv::Scalar(255), 1);

    cv::Mat I;
    Iu8.convertTo(I, CV_64FC1); //Convert from uint8 to double

    //Execute padding function
    cv::Mat J = PadImage(I, 101, 0);

    cv::Mat Ju8;
    J.convertTo(Ju8, CV_8UC1);  //Convert from double to uint8

    //Display input and output
    cv::imshow("Iu8", Iu8);
    cv::imshow("Ju8", Ju8);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

---

### Update

After posting your `main`, the problem can be found:

You are using `at<double>`, but image type is `uchar` (one byte per pixel).

Solution:

- Replace `at<double>` with `at<uchar>` when reading from and writing to image.
- Keep `at<double>` for the kernel, because the kernel type is `double`.

---

Here is the modified testing code (just for reference):

```
cv::Mat correlationPad(cv::Mat image, cv::Mat kernel, std::string padding_type)
{
    cv::Mat image_padded(image.rows + kernel.rows - 1, image.cols + kernel.cols - 1, image.type());
    image_padded = 0;
    cv::Mat result(image.rows, image.cols, image.type());
    result = 0;

    //cv::Mat image_padded2 = PadImage(image, 3, 3);

    //showImage(image, "Original Image");
    //showImage(image_padded2, "Image Padded");

    if (!padding_type.compare("zeros"))
    {
        int x_add = kernel.rows / 2, y_add = kernel.cols / 2;
        for (int i = x_add; i < image.rows + x_add; i++)
            for (int j = y_add; j < image.cols + y_add; j++)
                image_padded.at<uchar>(i, j) = image.at<uchar>(i - x_add, j - y_add);
    }
    /*else if (!padding_type.compare("repeat"))
    {
        cv::Mat result(image.rows + kernel.rows/2, image.cols + kernel.cols/2, image.type());

        for (int i = (kernel.rows-1)/2; i < image.rows + (kernel.rows-1)/2; i++)
            for (int j = (kernel.cols-1)/2; j < image.cols + (kernel.cols-1)/2; j++)
                result.at<double>(i, j) = image.at<double>(i-(kernel.rows-1)/2, j-((kernel.cols-1)/2));
    }*/
    else if (!padding_type.compare("without"))
    {
        //image_padded.release();
        //cv::Mat image_padded = image;
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "Please enter with a valid padding value." << std::endl;

    //showImage(image_padded, "Testing Padding");
    //cv::imwrite("Padding_image.jpg", image_padded);
    //for (int i = 0; i < result.rows; i++)
    //    for (int j = 0; j < result.cols; j++)
    //        for (int m = 0; m < kernel.rows; m++)
    //            for (int n = 0; n < kernel.cols; n++)
    //            {
    //                std::cout << image_padded.at<double>(i + m + kernel.rows / 2, j + n + kernel.cols / 2) << std::endl
    //                    << kernel.at<double>(m, n) << std::endl;
    //                result.at<double>(i, j) += image_padded.at<double>(i + m + kernel.rows / 2, j + n + kernel.cols / 2)*kernel.at<double>(m, n);
    //                std::cout << std::endl;
    //            }

    return image_padded;
}



int main()
{
    //Read input image as Grayscale (one byte per pixel).
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("square_landscape.jpeg");
    cv::Mat gray_image(image.rows, image.cols, image.type());
    cv::cvtColor(image, gray_image, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    //Draw a white rectangle around the input image (for testing)
    //cv::rectangle(gray_image, cv::Rect(0, 0, gray_image.cols - 1, gray_image.rows - 1), cv::Scalar(255), 1);

    cv::Mat sobel_x(3, 3, CV_64F);

    //Filling the Sobel Filter
    sobel_x.at<double>(0, 0) = -1;
    sobel_x.at<double>(0, 1) = -2;
    sobel_x.at<double>(0, 2) = -1;
    sobel_x.at<double>(1, 0) = 0;
    sobel_x.at<double>(1, 1) = 0;
    sobel_x.at<double>(1, 2) = 0;
    sobel_x.at<double>(2, 0) = 1;
    sobel_x.at<double>(2, 1) = 2;
    sobel_x.at<double>(2, 2) = 1;

    cv::Mat edge = correlationPad(gray_image, sobel_x, "zeros");

    cv::imwrite("edge.jpg", edge);  //Save result.

    //Display input and output
    cv::imshow("gray_image", gray_image);
    cv::imshow("edge", edge);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

---

edge:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Rotem. But I think that is not the problem. I'm using a kernel with size 3x3 which implies that the image will have to add 2 rows and 2 columns. The function I'm trying to implement does a correlation operation between the Image and the kernel. 

The kernel will always be odd.

Comment: Please post a code that reproduce the problem. Include sample input image, the code that reads the image, creating `kernel` parameters, executing the function, and the output. Preferable: Base you post on the code I posted. Have you tried executing my code sample with your input with `k_cols=3`, and `k_rows=3`?

Comment: I put the whole code in the question description, including your code. I tried to use your code, but I don't know why, but I can't visualize the images using the showImage() function that I get an error.

Comment: Here is the error I got: Image_Registration_2D: malloc.c:2401: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.

Comment: You are using `at<double>` instead of `at<uchar>`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Rotem. I'm fairly new into opencv and I didn't pay attention to that part.